# Datamapper gem dm-rails automigrate problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, datamapper

Trying to run db:automigrate doesn't work.  I get:

```
rake db:automigrate
(in /home/larsenal/rails/myapp)
rake aborted!
Adapter not set: default. Did you forget to setup?
```

Where is the adapter supposed to be setup?  My ignorant first view of things suggests that it should figure that out form the database.yml.  Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: If you could give us more details about your system I'm sure your answer could be found. For me I got this error on OSX when installing with the incorrect mysql adapter installed. Follow these instructions if that is the case. http://wiki.rubyonrails.org/database-support/mysql

Answer (score 0):

Did you installed adapter gems like a dm-mysql-adapter or maybe not installed database client/server on your system?